# Adding one of my NuGet packages to a project pulls in a bunch of .NET Core assemblies that are not referenced

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a project that I built as a NuGet package, it is a .NET 4.6.2 class library.

When I pull it into another project, it wants to add a bunch of references that look like .NET core assemblies. The project is not .NET core, and in the NuGet package manager none of these are referenced, nor are they referenced in the References folder. Here is a screenshot:

[image: List of references]

I did a find in all files to look for them and there were no results. The project it's trying to pull in looks like this in NuGet:

[image: List of included packages]

Note that there are none of the System.xxx references in the initial screenshot.

The packages.config matches the included packages screenshot above - no reference to those System.xxx libraries.

Can anyone explain this behaviour so I can fix it?

Comment: They look like PCL reference assemblies.  Rings a bell?

Comment: Hmm, project isn't a PCL (also double-checked the proj file to confirm this)